# Recuperar Cookies em autenticação com Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, cookies, spring-security, request

Como posso recuperar os cookies quando o usuário efetuar o login através do Spring Security e com a implementação da interface `AuthenticationProvider`? Se eu recuperar uma instância de `HttpServletRequest` a partir de uma classe com controladora tenho acesso aos Cookies, porém se fazer dessa forma retorna `null` o atributo com os Cookies:

**Obs**: Tenho os Cookies setados, são exibidos no *DevTools* do Chrome.

**Código**:

```
@Component
public class LoginAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication)
            throws AuthenticationException {

        /* Aqui tento recuperar os cookies */
        RequestAttributes requestAttributes = RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
        HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) requestAttributes).getRequest();
        /* Aqui tento recuperar os cookies */

        String username =  authentication.getName().toString();
        String password = (String) authentication.getCredentials();

        if (! AuthenticationConvert.validaSchema(username)) {
            throw new SchemaNotFoundException();
        } 

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);   


        Usuario usuario = usuarioService.findUsuario(AuthenticationConvert.getLogin(authentication.getName().toString()));  

        if (usuario == null)
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Usuário não encontrado.");

        if (! usuario.getSenha().equalsIgnoreCase(password))
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Senha incorreta.");

        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password, null);
    }

}
```

**Imagem**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Existe outra maneira para recuperar os cookies a partir de uma autenticação? Qual?

Answer (score 0):

É possivel recuperar com uma annotation, realizando binding atravez de um parametro.

```
public void metodo(@CookieValue("nome") String cookie) {

}
```

Para adicionar é preciso de um `HttpServletResponse`

```
public void metodo2(HttpServletResponse response) {
   Cookie cookie = new Cookie("chave", "valor");
   //configurações do cookie
   response.addCookie(cookie);
}
```

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-cookievalue

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-cookie-example/

Comment: Obrigado @DouglasGaldino, dessa forma já conheço. O problema é que o método `authenticate` esta com a anotação `@Override` sendo um método da interface implementada na classe, portanto não posso alterar o método colocando mais um parâmetro com uma instância de `HttpServletResponse`.

Comment: :] É necessário que os cookies sejam recuperados antes da autenticação?

Comment: Isso mesmo que é necessário.

Comment: Entendo, caso não fosse, poderia utilizar um handler (successHandler), que recebe request, response e authentication nos parametros ao extender de SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler

Comment: Cheguei a utilizar a interface `AuthenticationEntryPoint` porém funciona apenas quando o usuário acessa a aplicação, e não quando faz o login nela, porém irei pesquisar por alternativas depois. Estava utilizando o seguinte material, veja se lhe interessa também: http://pawel-malczyk.pl/wordpress/?p=291

Comment: Interessa sim, não conhecia algumas das implementações, podem ser úteis em futuras situações, Obrigado.

Comment: Acabei de conhecer hoje inclusive haha de nada